# How to get protobuf-net serializer nonstatic instance?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I use protobuf-net serializer like this:

```
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(fileStream, data);
```

How do I get a non-static serializer instance? I want to use it something like this:

```
var myProtobufNetSerializer = MyProtobufNetSerializerFactory();
myProtobufNetSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, data);
```

#### Edit:

Marc Gravell, the protobuf-net's author, replied (to [this question](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/05/protobuf-net-v2-beta.html?showComment=1312394581676#c294543940248490355)) in [his answer that it's possible](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/05/protobuf-net-v2-beta.html?showComment=1312397400001#c4105202691328149305), but I couldn't find how...

Comment: Which protobuf serializer are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, do you mean what version? 2.0.0.668

Comment: Good question, I don´t think it is possible though. The implementation only provides static methods to my knowledge. May I ask you to shed some light on the broader perspective - why do you need an instance?

Comment: @Marcus, see my edit - the author claims it's possible... there are many use cases (unit testing, IoC/DI, extension methods [as suggested in the referred question in my edit], ...)

Comment: @Marcus it is very possible; but whether it is *appropriate* depends a lot on the scenario.

Comment: Then I guess, my mistake, please carry on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important question I have is *why* do you want to do that? The `static` methods actually just expose the v1 API on the default instanc, aka `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`. So I *could* answer  your question with just:

```
TypeModel serializer = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
```

However, there would be very little benefit to doing this - you might just as well use the `static` methods. If, however, you want to do something *more interesting*, then you probably want a custom model:

```
RuntimeTypeModel serializer = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
// exercise for reader: configure it, store it somewhere, re-use it
```

You should **not** create a new `TypeModel` per serialization required, since the `TypeModel` (or more specifically: `RuntimeTypeModel`) caches the generated strategies internally. It would be inefficient and a memory drain to keep doing this unnecessarily.

Times when you might not want to use the default type-model:

- you need to support 2 different incompatible layouts (perhaps for versioning reasons) *at the same time*
- you are using a runtime that doesn't support reflection-emit, and must use pre-built serializer types
- you are doing unit testing *of the library itself*
- probably a few others that I'm not remembering